# Xcode : Search Bar Filtering

Tags: xcode, uitableview, sqlite, uisearchdisplaycontroller

Hy all, i have developed an application that searches a table view connected to a sqlite database.
A search Bar is added onto of the application and the search is working fine, but when i type, i need only the items STARTING by the letter typed appear.
This is my code till now :

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar*)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString*)text
{
    if(text.length == 0)
    {
        isFiltered = FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        isFiltered = true;
        filteredTableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (Author* author in theauthors)
        {  //[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELECT * from books where title LIKE %@", searchBar.text];
            NSRange nameRange = [author.name rangeOfString:text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            NSRange descriptionRange = [author.genre rangeOfString:text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            if(nameRange.location != NSNotFound || descriptionRange.location != NSNotFound)
            {
                [filteredTableData addObject:author];
            }
        }
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was actually pretty simple. I just had to change the options file from options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch to option:NSAnchoredSearch
It worked like a charm